# Get the variables set in 'this' by a function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which adds some variables in `this`, for example:

```
this.a = "hello";
this.b = "bye";
```

The `this` of this function is an image,

```
$('#image').function1();
```

Now I want to access these variables in another function. I am calling this function the same way:

```
$('#image').function2();
```

but when I try to access `this.a` and `this.b`, `undefined` is thrown.

How can I access these variables from function2?

Comment: try anonymous functions

Comment: @ImmortalDude both of these are anonymous functions

Comment: `this` only exists in the context of the function where it's run. After that it's destroyed. Since you're using jQuery, try using data-properties on the element instead, as these will persist for the lifetime of the page. `$("#image1").data("a", "hello");` to set it, and `alert($("#image1").data("a"));` to retrieve it.

Comment: `$('#image') !== $('#image')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.fn.functionName` to extend prototype with new method that will add new properties in your case `a` and `b` to object that you call this method on, and then in another method you can access those properties.

`$` or `jQuery` is a constructor function and `fn` is same as `prototype`

```js
$.fn.function1 = function() {
  this.a = 'hello';
  this.b = 'bye';
  return this;
}

$.fn.function2 = function() {
  console.log(this.a)
}

$('img').function1().function2()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you basically just want to pass variables from one function to another. I'd use one of those approaches.

1st.

```
var _this = {};

var function1 = function(){
    [YOUR CODE];
    _this.a = 'hello';
    _this.b = 'bye';
    }

var function2 = function(){
[dosomething with _this.a and _this.b]
```

Another way would be to call the function2 from the first one which I would prefer.

```
var function2 = function(a,b){
[doSomethingWithThoseValues]
};
var function1 = function(){
var a = 'hello';
var b = 'bye';
function2(a,b);
}
```

Hope I understood correctly what you wanted to meant. If not, just leave a comment

Greetings Chris

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure JavaScript solution:

```
function function1() {
  this.a = 'hello 2u';
  this.b = 'goodbye';
  return [this.a,this.b];
}

function function2(obj){
  this.a = obj.function1()[0];
  this.b = obj.function1()[1];
  console.log(this.a + " " + this.b);
}
var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
var image2 = document.getElementById("image2");

image1.function1 = function1;
image2.function2 = function2;
image2.function2( image1 );
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKxpPL)

Given the officially accepted answer, surely this pure-JavaScript example can be improved, as follows:

HTML:

```
<img src="" id="image"><br>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");

image.function1 = function() {
  this.a = "hello 2 the world";
  this.b = "goodbye";
  return this;
};

image.function2 = function() {
  console.log(this.a + " " + this.b);
  };

image.function1().function2();
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmdqMz)

By returning **this**, the methods may be chained together and the properties **a** and **b** are available to the second method. If you wish to avoid method chaining, the second method could invoke the first method, as follows:

```
image.function2 = function() {
  this.image.function1();
  console.log(this.image.a + " " + this.image.b);
  }();
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmvBdN)